# Set up react-native-permissions for NX repo

Tags: react-native, react-native-permissions

I'm having trouble setting up react-native-permissions for the NX repo

I added reactNativePermissionsIOS in package.json but when run app show "no permission handler detected". I am in react-native 0.71.11 and Xcode 14.3.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by putting the `reactNativePermissionsIOS` section in the app's `package.json`, changing to that directory then running the command: `npx react-native setup-ios-permissions` as stated [here](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#ios).

From what I can infer, the command actually modifies the `react-native-permissions` `RNPermissions.podspec` file line 17. For my use case I needed "Notifications". Below you can see how the podspec was modified by appending `, "ios/Notifications/*.{h,m,mm}"`.

```
s.source_files = "ios/*.{h,m,mm}", "ios/Notifications/*.{h,m,mm}"
```

Comment: I raised an issue with the library author and they have developed a nicer way to do this. Please see https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions/issues/799 for more information.